# Single table with multiple views or Multiple table?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a sqlite database for my android app with a single table with around 500 rows and 10 columns.
Is there will be any performance improvement if i split my table into multiple tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a single table has the best performance (in most cases). With a single table you prevent usage of JOINS which are very bad for the performance. Also 500 rows isn't realy that much.

You could consider using multiple tables if there is a lot of redundancy in your database. For example: Some object has a type and there are 20 different types. Storing these types again and again for each object consumes a lot of space. It is a good idea to create a relation in this case so you only need 20 types and connect them with your object.